# Accessing text/template contents in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I'm trying to access the html contents of an script block with the type set to "text/template". I've heard of template engines using such tags, but my application is very simple and loading an entire engine is unnecessary. Can someone shed some light on how I select that element? I think jQuery's .html() function will get me the content but I can't seem to find the element.

The template looks like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="repeating-form-section-template">
  <div class="repeating-form-section">
    <label>Field Name:</field>
    <input type="text" value="default value" name="field_name" />
  </div>
</script>
```

Things I've tried:

```
getElementById('repeating-form-section-template');
$('script').filter(...);
$('#repeating-form-section-template');
$("script[type='text/template']");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need help also with template _tags_. This is different as you need to process them first.

Comment: I seem to have no problem with this ([click here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/XM2uv/)). You are loading the text/template part before the jQuery and then your own script, right? One other slight issue might be the malformed HTML (`<label>Field Name:</field>`).

Comment: This is what Im guessing if its not getting the content at all. I updated my answer too.

Comment: I forgot to trigger the function after the load event; my mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both:

```
 $('#repeating-form-section-template');
 $("script[type='text/template']");
```

Work fine. Make sure you check them after DOM load. Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/VKqPX/

Comment: Thanks, I was not loading the script after DOM load.

Answer (score 1):

It should be this easy:

http://jsbin.com/evozi5/edit

For a preview:
http://jsbin.com/evozi5/

The code tho is simply:

```
var someVar = $('#repeating-form-section-template').html();

$('#where-i-want-content').append(someVar);
```

**Note**

jQuery must be loaded *before* this will work tho. So:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script> /* your code */ </script>
<script type="text/template"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is generally considered a bad thing to use, but it's the perfect thing to use here:

```
var template = document.getElementById("repeating-form-section-template").innerHTML;

document.getElementById('where-you-want-the-content').innerHTML = template;
```